# How to solve error -2147467259 when querying large amounts of data in AZURE ML

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-postgresql

I am trying to fetch a decent amount of data in Azure ML from a postgresql DB. When I limit the amount of data returned (e.g. LIMIT 100 000) the query executes as expected. However when I remove this limit (and fetch the complete 2 000 000 rows), the query fails and returns an exit code (-2147467259). There is some solutions on how to deal with this but nothing applicable to AZURE ML.

EDIT1: Loading this (full set of) data in pandas for example does not give any issues. The problem really seems to be with Azure ML

Answer (score 0):

Generally error -2147467259 occurs while SQL installation, which is not relevant in your case. This is unexpected behavior in case of Azure ML.

You may raise ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/)